# Set another class' property

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to set an NSString property of a main view from a nested view. I do so right now by allocating the previous class and accessing the `class.property`. When I pop the view controller programmatically and NSLog the property from the main view, it's null.

How does this happen?

EDIT:

```
MainViewController *controller = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        controller.category = @"Categorie 1";
        break;
    default:
        break;
} 
[controller release];
```

Comment: Can you post some code to see what are you doing?

Comment: A code sample would be appreciated. However I think you should not set the property on the right object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you are going to pop the viewController so I assume you are trying to set a property of the controller below the navigation stack.

Instead of creating a new object of the class, you should get back the original object that was already created.

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers]; // array of viewControllers currently on the navigation stack.
MainVC *mainVC = (mainVC *)[viewControllers objectAtIndex:viewControllers.count - 2];
[mainVC setProperty:...];
```

Comment: Thanks! Like magic, but exactly the opposite! :) Upvoted and accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, you cannot access a specific instance's properties by simply calling the class.  The class has no connection to any specific instance of it.

You need to have an instance variable in your nested view that references the parent.  set this up when you create it.  Then when you are in the child view controller you can still access the parent.

Something like this in the child:

```
MyParentViewController *parentVC;
```